# Printed data from Firebase Realtime Database is in different order than shown in console

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Output in console:

[image: Output]

Code:

```
FirebaseDatabase base = FirebaseDatabase( );
database = base.reference();
DataSnapshot? snap = await database!.get();
print(snap!.value);
```

Database data:

[image: Database]

I think the problem is due to nested data in database, Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I see no problem. The data is printed as it should.

Comment: but its coming in wrong order. See the console After switch 1 ,switch 3 is showing but in database it is saved as switch 1 and then switch 2

Comment: You need to order the data in your code

Comment: yup i got it ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it seems you are asking why the order from `print(snap!.value)` is different from the order in the console. This is because neither of those orders is guaranteed, since the order of properties in JSON is undefined.

The console just happens to show the keys in alphabetical order, while the `Map` that you get back from `snap!.value` doesn't.

If you want to get the results ordered by key in the map too, you'll need to do two things:

1. Ask Firebase for the results ordered by key.
2. Then handle the order in your code, instead of converting to a map (which might lose the ordering again).

In code:

```
DataSnapshot? snap = await database!.child("Room 1").orderByKey().get(); 
  //   child("Room 1") requests only the child nodes of Room 1
  //   orderByKey() requests the child nodes ordered by their key
print(snap!.value.values); //  requesting values results in a list
```

Comment: ok I got it!!! But i will be adding more rooms to my database. So what should I do to get the rooms and switches in the right order from database?

Comment: The order of properties in JSON is undefined, and while you can use Firebase's `orderBy...` operations to tell it to return the direct child nodes, there is no such operation for deeper level properties. So you'll have to reorder those properties in your application code, after retrieving them from Firebase.